# How to change specific dataframe column values using loc or iloc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I stupidly replaced al values in my dataframe above 5 to be `True` without realizing one column is the transaction number. Is there a way I can locate the 5 values in a single column and change them all from true back to 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5?

```
df_bdPivot = pd.read_csv("BreadBasket_DMS_pivot.csv")
df_bdPivot.fillna(False, inplace=True)
df_bdPivot.replace(1, True, regex=True, inplace=True)
df_bdPivot.replace(2, True, regex=True, inplace=True)
df_bdPivot.replace(3, True, regex=True, inplace=True)
df_bdPivot.replace(4, True, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

If there's a way to do what I did without tweaking the column I need to keep the same, please let me know.

Comment: Try this: `df_bdPivot[(df_bdPivot > 0) & (df_bdPivot < 6)] = True`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df_bdPivot[(df_bdPivot > 0) & (df_bdPivot < 6)] = True
```

What that does, is it takes two *masks* (`df_bdPivot > 0` and `df_bdPivot < 6`), and joins them together `&`, and uses the resulting mask to select values from the dataframe, and then assign `True` to those values.

A mask is just a copy of the dataframe, only instead of the values it had, there are only `True` values or `False` values. The two masks respectively select values that are greater then 0, and less than 6 (so 1 through 5). The `&` creates a new mask where, for each value, it's `True` if that value in *both* of the dataframes is `True`, `False` otherwise.